# What is the purpose of F() and FPSTR() in ESP8266WebServer -> FSBrowser?

Tags: esp8266, c++, string

I found this [code sample](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/a4b6003c2e5f27fcce42124f2ffef824fb90339d/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/FSBrowser/FSBrowser.ino#L177-L183) from the FSBrowser (Flash File System) example in the [ESP8266WebServer](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer) library:

```c
replyServerError(FPSTR(FS_INIT_ERROR));
replyBadRequest(F("DIR ARG MISSING"));
```

I was a bit confused at what `F()` and `FPSTR()` do, so I looked up the source (`WString.h`) and found this:

```c
#define FPSTR(pstr_pointer) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(pstr_pointer))
#define F(string_literal) (FPSTR(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

Which raised more questions. How does this code work and what does this added complexity gain over just using `char*` or `String` as is?

#### EDIT: Added Metrics

Here's the memory usage before and after I removed all 25 instances of F() from a file system class, measured by PlatformIO Project Inspector:

|  | With F() | Without F() | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RAM Used | 29,488 bytes (36.0%) | 29,792 bytes (36.4%) | +304 bytes |
| Flash Used | 355,312 bytes (34%) | 355,188 bytes (34.0%) | -124 bytes |
| Total (uncompressed) | 359,472 bytes | 359,344 bytes | -128 bytes |

Adding F() decreases RAM usage by 1% and increases Flash by around half that. That's for a single class with 25 instances of F(). For a program containing 20x this code, the difference can be significant. However, you'll run out of RAM before you get there. The space savings will be limited to around 5-8%. Still not nothing.

Comment: On the ESP32 (as well as most 32-bit boards), the macros are nothing but a cast, on AVR-based boards (i.e. Arduino Uno), special low-level functions are required to read data from flash. The macros are hiding this difference from the user, so that the code can be written such that it compiles and runs on both platforms.

Comment: @PMF thanks for clarifying the use case. Does that mean I don't need to use `F()` or `FPSTR()` in my own code if I only plan on using the ESP8266?

Comment: I think not, but it may still depend on the compiler (it may still do a copy from Flash to Ram on bootup). You can find out by adding/removing a few F()'s and check the resulting RAM usage (last line of the compiler output). If it doesn't change, you don't need it.

Comment: On the ESP8266 for sure, F() macros can save heap space.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks! I added an edit with some metrics. The code author sometimes uses F(), sometimes FPSTR(), and sometimes neither. What is a good criteria to decide when to use each approach?

Comment: it will save more ram with longer strings, like web page error messages for example. Use `F()` pretty much only on string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `PSTR()` macro is to configure the string to be used directly from flash memory. The string is then not loaded to dynamic memory at runtime as it would be without [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) specifier set by the macro.

The purpose of the `FPSTR()` macro is to cast a string to 'dummy' FlashStringHelper type to help compiler choose the right overloaded function if dynamic memory and flash memory version of a function is available. An example would be the `print` function.

The `F()` macro combines this two macros. It makes the string a PROGMEM string and casts it to FlashStringHelper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How does FlashStringHelper help function overloading? Does it cast itself to either a dynamic string or flash string depending on its input parameter?

Comment: @DV82XL, PROGMEM string is const char* too. in C there are functions like sprintf_P for PROGMEM strings , but Arduino decided to use a special 'dummy' type for the PROGMEM string and uses `print(const char*)` for normal string and `print(flashstringhelper*)` for PROGMEM string. there is no Serial.print_P in standard Arduino API (some cores have it). to use the right function the C++ compiler evaluates the parameters of functions with same name https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/9f8d27f09f3bbd1da1374b5549a82bda55d45d44/cores/arduino/Print.h#L65